# How to unit test the Spring WebClient in java?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have this code which uses WebClient to call a third party API.

```
    public Mono<JsonNode> callApi(String url) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(url)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set(Constants.X_API_KEY, apiKey))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        res -> {
                            res.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                    .subscribe(e -> log.error(Constants.EXCEPTION_LOG, e));
                            return Mono.error(new RetryableException("Server error: " + res.rawStatusCode()));
                        })
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        res -> {
                            res.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                    .subscribe(e -> log.error("Exception occurred in callPartnerApi: No retries {}", e));
                            return Mono.error(new Exception("Exception occurred calling partner api, no retries " + res.rawStatusCode()));
                        })
                .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
    }
```

I am trying to use Mockito to unit test this and so far I have this which is failing:

```
    @Test
    void testCallPartnerApi_then5xxException() {
        WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec.class);
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);

        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
        when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).then(invocationOnMock -> Mono.error(new RetryableException("Server error: 500")));

        when(responseSpec.onStatus(argThat(x -> x.test(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)), any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> Mono.error(new RetryableException("Server error: 500")));


        StepVerifier.create(partnerService.callPartnerApi("/test"))
                .expectError()
                .verify();
    }
```

The error I get from this test is this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.MonoError cannot be cast to class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$ResponseSpec
```

Is using a library like WireMock or MockServerTest the only way to test these scenarios?

Answer (score 5):

Unit testing WebClient has very low ROI. I would recommend looking at  [WireMock](https://wiremock.org) that provides very good API for testing web clients. Here are some examples

```
stubFor(get(url)
        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody("{}")
        )
);

StepVerifier.create(service.callApi())
        .expectNextCount(1)
        .verifyComplete();
```

You could easily test both positive and negative scenarios by providing different stubs

```
stubFor(get(url)
        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(500)
        )
);
```

In addition, you could test retry logic using [Scenarios](https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) or even simulate timeouts using [Delays](https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/).

To initialize it you could use `@AutoConfigureWireMock`provided by `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock` or, as an alternative, you can add direct dependency to `WireMock` and initialize it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

We use Wiremock to test Client functionality. It can be done in standard unit test or a SpringBoot test.

Below code explains the Unit testing in regular tests.

```
@Service
class MoviesClient {
  private final WebClient moviesWebClient;

  public Mono<Movie> findMovieById(String movieID) {
    return moviesWebClient.get().uri(MOVIE_ENDPOINT+"/"+movieID).bodyValue(job).retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Movie.class);
  }
}
```

Now as we see MoviesClient needs webClient to call the movie service and get movie.

```
  @ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class})
    class MoviesClientTest {
    
        private MoviesClient moviesClient;
        
        @RegisterExtension
          private static final WireMockExtension MOVIES_WM =
         WireMockExtension.newInstance().options(wireMockConfig().port("8086")).build();
        
        @BeforeEach
        void setup() {
        
        var webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8086")
                .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build();
        moviesClient = new MoviesClient(moviesClient)
MOVIES_WM.stubFor(get(MOVIE_ENDPOINT+"/"+"1234")).withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, matching(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(OK.value()).withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .withBody("Your json response body comes here")));
        }
}
```

Now you can write your tests to call the method on client which in turn will make a webclient call which will be stubbed to wiremock server.

```
@Test
void testMoviesEndPoint() {
  StepVerifier.create(moviesClient.findMovieById(1234)
  .expectNext(movie -> assertThat(movie).getId.equals(1234))
  .verifyComplete();

FLUENT_WM.verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(MOVIE_ENDPOINT+"/"+"1234")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

requestHeadersSpec.retrieve() return ResponseSpec, but you are trying to return Mono.error by mockito instead. You need to return result of valid type, something that can be inherited from ResponseSpec.
You may return mock of ResponseSpec or something like
new DefaultResponseSpec(Mono.error(new RetryableException("Server error: 500")))

```
    static class DefaultResponseSpec implements ResponseSpec {
        private final Mono<ClientResponse> responseMono;

        DefaultResponseSpec(Mono<ClientResponse> responseMono) {
            this.responseMono = responseMono;
        }
```